# Unknown cause of exception

Tags: java, eclipse

Every time I run this, I get an error that reads: "Exception in thread 'main' java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero". I'm not sure why this isn't working.

```
public static void Solve(long num){
    for(int x = 1; x < num; x++){
        if((num % x) == 0){    //error occurs here
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `num`?

Comment: you could check the values you are working with before the if-statement is executed to get an idea of what numbers are used in the calculation

Comment: There are accepted answers here, but in your question it says it happens "every time I run this". Just want to be sure: does it only happen for large values of num, or for all values?

Comment: I had only tested large values, so that ended up being the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`num` is a `long`. When you compare an `int` with a `long` like `x < num`, the `int` will be promoted to a `long`. Assuming your `num` is big enough (bigger than the max value of an `int`), `x` will never reach it and your `x++` will be executed. At some point, the value of `x` will overflow and become `0`.

Answer (score 3):

Since num is a long, if you choose it sufficiently large, x, which is only an int, will overflow. And when it does that, as an int it will be zero. And then you get zero-divide in the remainder operation.